# How to enable Fulltext using query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to enable fulltext search using query in sql server 2008 R2?

I have setup database in Amzon RDS. There is no support to enable fulltext.
Please let me know if there is any way to enable fulltext using query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in 2008 and above, full text indexing is enabled by default and cannot be disabled.

With that said, I've not used RDS before but you could try the old SQL 2000 syntax below

```
USE [database];
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable';
GO
```

Regardless, the full text service has to be running. If it is not, then you will not be able to run full text indexes at all.